# What is the best way to return data to users when using event-driven microservices?

Tags: events, socket.io, rabbitmq, microservices, messaging

I am using a microservice architecture for this current project using RabbitMQ as a message broker. My issue is determining the best possible way to make "requests" to the microservices and return back the eventual response, currently I have a socket.io socket running and connecting the browser client to that and sending events to the socket, the socket reads the events and publishes them into RabbitMQ, and of course they are then consumed by the services.

So my question:

Is my current setup good enough to just keep using or is there other ways that are better?

Comment: You could just use STOMP - Rabbit supports it natively. But what "good enough" and "better" mean are wholly subjective - what are the criteria of assessment here?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Mainly its ability to be easily maintainable and scalable.